# debuggable false in Android Studio 0.5.1

Tags: android, debugging

in the version 0.4.2 i write in the AndroidManifest

android:debuggable="false" to upload to play.store

but in the 0.5.1, i do not what to do.
Please, help me.

y resolved my problem with

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    foo{
        debuggable false //add this
    }
}
```

in the androidmanifest

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the problem with

```
buildTypes {
release {
    runProguard false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
}
foo{
    debuggable false //add this
}
```

}